# Ajuda com o erro SQL 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

Poderiam me ajudar a resolver esse problema aqui?

```
use bancoteste:
create TABLE login{nome varchar(10),senha varchar(10));
INSERT into login VALUES (`root´,`root´);
SELECT * from login
```

Erro:

> Erro SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':
>   create TABLE login{nome varchar(10),senha varchar(10))' at line 1

Comment: Você colocou dois pontos na frente do "bancoteste" coloque ponto e vírgula

Answer (score 4):

Existem **3** problemas com os comandos que indicou na sua questão:

**1.** Dois pontos ao invés de ponto e vírgula em:

`use bancoteste:`

**2.** Chaveta (**{**) ao invés de parêntesis (**(**) em:

`create TABLE login{nome varchar(10),senha varchar(10));`

**3.** Caracteres inválidos ao definir um texto em:

`INSERT into login VALUES (´root´,´root´);`

---

*Queries* corretas e estruturadas:

```
USE bancoteste;

CREATE TABLE login
(
        nome    VARCHAR(10)
    ,   senha   VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO login 
VALUES ('root', 'root');

SELECT  * 
FROM    login;
```

Answer (score 1):

Existem erros de sintaxe na criação da tabela e na inserção dos dados.

`CREATE TABLE login(nome varchar(10),senha varchar(10));`

`INSERT into login VALUES ('root','root');`

Tutorial criar tabela - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

Tutorial inserir dados - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp